# check login state, render an overlay if not logged in and continue if login succeeded

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I use Vuejs with Vuetify and Vuex and want to create a simple app. Let's say a very small todo app. For my backend I use an Express REST api and for the HTTP methods I use Axios.

To handle the session I read about two things:

When launching an Axios call I could get an error with the status code `401`. I could deal with it using `axios.interceptors.response`.

```
  instance.interceptors.response.use(res => res, (err) => {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch('authentication/destroySession');
    }

    return err;
  });
```

When redirecting to another route I could use the `beforeRouteEnter` event of the `Vue Router` and check if the token is valid and not expired.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const userIsLoggedIn = checkIfUserIsLoggedIn();

  if (!userIsLoggedIn) {
    next(false); // stay on this route
  } else {
    next(); // navigate to the next route
  }
});
```

So far so good. But what happens if one of these approaches have to deal with a "not logged in" state? I don't want to redirect the user to a login page because then he would loose his current work. And maybe he got no account so he needs to signup first.

If the route or REST endpoint is protected I would cancel the task to execute, show an error alert and after that I would like to render an overlay.

Most resources explain how to redirect to the login page if not logged in but Github for example renders the login page and executes the task after logging in.

How can I render this overlay? Is it even possible? Is there a better approach?

Comment: In beforeRouteEnter, you can call `next(false)` to abort navigation, then set some state to reactively trigger the display of an overlay

Comment: @Dan yes but my only question is how can I display an overlay without removing the current view :) This would happen in my `App.vue` but I don't know how to setup such an overlay

Comment: I've posted an answer to show you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create the overlay HTML (can be in `App.vue` as you mentioned) whose visibility is dependent upon a computed called `showOverlay`:

   ```
   <div v-show="showOverlay">OVERLAY CONTENT</div>
   ```
2. In your Vuex store, maintain some state which represents the visibility of the overlay:

   ```
   state.showOverlay = false;
   ```
3. Back in `App.vue`, map this Vuex state into the `showOverlay` computed:

   ```
   import { mapState } from 'vuex';
   export default {
     computed: {
       ...mapState(['showOverlay'])
     }
   }
   ```
4. Wherever you use `beforeRouteEnter`, or in the router if using `beforeEach`, import the Vuex store directly (this makes it easy to access the store when `this.$store` is not accessible):

   ```
   import store from '@/store.js';
   ```
5. I see you posted example code which uses `beforeEach` instead of `beforeRouteEnter`, so use something like:

   ```
   router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
     const userIsLoggedIn = checkIfUserIsLoggedIn();

     if (!userIsLoggedIn) {
       store.state.showOverlay = true;
       next(false); // stay on this route
     } else {
       next(); // navigate to the next route
     }
   });
   ```

After you get this working, it would be best to move the overlay into a component to avoid needlessly editing `App.vue`.  And you'll need to set the overlay's state back to `false` on close.

Comment: This seems to use a different, valid approach.  Showing a sign in component if the user is not logged in.  But you mentioned not wanting to redirect to a page like this and asked how to use an overlay instead :)

Comment: thanks but I think I didn't get your first point. What is the difference? How would you manage this overlay then? Without using a if-statement? I think I did not understand your solution because I think my approach would be yours ...

Comment: The difference: In your original question, you imagined a user doing work on a non-protected route and then attempting some action that required login.  In your 2nd example, the app root shows nothing if the user is not logged in, so the work you envisioned would not be possible in the first place.  Your original question does not even need `beforeRouteEnter`, because you could just show the overlay when the user clicks `Save` or whatever the login-required action is. 
 I think you have several design patterns mixed up.

Comment: Based on our comments, I think what you really want is to show a signin overlay *before* you send the Axios request, if the user is not logged in.